# Schutz - A first course in GR - Measuring distances with light

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, gravitational-waves

In chapter 9 of Schutz's book "A first course in General Relativity" there is a calculation that computes the effect of gravitational waves on the travel time of photons exchanged from two objects.

The author assumes that the first body (located at the origin) sends a photon to the second body, located at $x=L$, at the time $t_{start}$. Subsequently, the second body reflects the photon back to the first body, which receives it at the time $t_{return}$. All of this happens when a plane gravitational wave in the TT gauge with only $+$-polarization, i.e. $h_+(t) \ne 0$ and $h_\times(t) = 0$, crosses perpendicularly the axis where the two objects are located.

After some calculations, the result is
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{d}t_{return}}{\mathrm{d}t_{start}} \simeq 1 + \frac{1}{2}\left[ h_+\left( t_{start} + \frac{2L}{c}\right)-h_+\left( t_{start}\right) \right] 
\end{equation}

I have no problems with this result but rather with what the author writes next

> This is rather a remarkable result: the rate of change of the return time depends only on the
> metric of the wave at the time the wave was emitted and when it was received back at the
> origin. In particular, the wave amplitude when the photon reflected off the distant object
> plays no role.
> Now, if the signal sent out from the origin is not a single photon but a continuous electromagnetic wave with some frequency $\nu$, then each ‘crest’ of the wave can be thought
> of as another null ray or another photon being sent out and reflected back. The derivative
> of the time it takes these rays to return is nothing more than the change in the frequency of
> the electromagnetic wave:
> \begin{equation}
> \frac{\mathrm{d}t_{return}}{\mathrm{d}t_{start}} = \frac{\nu_{return}}{\nu_{start}} 
> \end{equation}
> So if we monitor changes in the redshift of the returning wave, we can relate that directly
> to changes in the amplitude of the gravitational waves.

**I do not understand how you can write the equality between the derivative of time and the ratio of frequencies.**

Besides that, I would expect intuitively the opposite to be true, that is
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{d}t_{return}}{\mathrm{d}t_{start}} = \frac{\nu_{start}}{\nu_{return}} 
\end{equation}

Comment: Well, the more $t_{return}$ passes the more photons (or "chrests") will have come back.

Comment: @AndreaAlciato Not sure about this, if the time between subsequent crests increases as well

Comment: To get an idea, compare time and frequency in a weak field $\tau = \frac{x^{0}}{c}(1-\frac{\varphi}{c^{2}})$ and $\nu=\nu_ {0} (1-\frac{\varphi}{c^{2}})$, with $g_{ij}=n_{ij}+h_{ij}\;,h_{ij}<<n_{ij}$

Comment: @TheTiler can you elaborate more? You are saying that in the weak-field limit time and frequency scale in the same way? How can you derive that?

Comment: See : http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/gratim.html    $(\nu=\nu_{0}(1-\varphi/c^{2})  $     and  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_time_dilation  where $t_{0}=t_{f}\sqrt{1-2GM/rc^{2}} ==t_{f}(1-\varphi/c^{2})$ for $GM<<c^{2}$